# задачи на палиндромы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, символы

> В первой строке входных данных содержится число N (1 <= N <= 100000). Во второй строке задается последовательность из N больших латинских букв (буквы записаны без пробелов). ребуется из данных букв по указанным правилам составить палиндром наибольшей длины, а если таких палиндромов несколько, то выбрать первый из них в алфавитном порядке.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string>
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int i, j, oi = 0;
string a, outpit;
char z;
bool flag = true;

void work() {
  for (j = 0; j < a.size(); ++j) {
    if (i == j) j++;
    if (a[i] == a[j]) {
      cout << a << endl;
      outpit[oi] = a[i];
      oi++;
      a[i] = i;
      return;
    }
  }
  if (flag == true) {
    z = a[i];
    flag = false;
  }
  return;
}

int main() {
  int h;
  cin >> h;
  cin >> a;
  sort(a.begin(), a.end());
  for (i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    work();
  }
  for (i = 0; i < oi; i += 2)
    cout << outpit[i];

  if (flag == false)
    cout << z;

  for (i = oi - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2)
    cout << outpit[i];

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я писал код, вот

Comment: #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    int i,j,oi=0;
    string a,outpit;
    char z;
    bool flag=true;
    void work(){
      for(j=0;j<a.size();++j){
        if(i==j)j++;
        if(a[i]==a[j]){
          cout<<a<<endl;
          outpit[oi]=a[i];
          oi++;
          a[i]=i;
          return;
        }
      }
      if(flag==true){
          z=a[i];
          flag=false;
       }
       return;
    }

Comment: int main() {
    int h;
    cin>>h;
     cin>>a;
     sort (a.begin(),a.end());
     for(i=0;i<a.size();++i){
     work();
     }
     for(i=0;i<oi;i+=2)
     cout<<outpit[i];
     if(flag==false)
       cout<<z;
     for(i=oi-1;i>=0;i-=2)
     cout<<outpit[i];
     return 0;
    }

Comment: Код не работает на нечетном числе букв

Comment: Внесите код в ответ и поясните, что понимать под "указанными правилами". Для начала.

Comment: Указанные правиа- палиндром, из данных букв

Comment: я не знаю как добавить код в ответ

Comment: Добавлять код надо в вопрос, нажав под ним "править".

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если там точно (!) N символов во второй строке и без пробелов, то можно сразу читать строку символов и обрабатывать:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s,p;
    cin >> s;
    cin >> s;
    sort(s.begin(),s.end());
    char center = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == s[i+1])
        {
            p += s[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if (center == 0) center = s[i];
    }
    s = p;
    reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
    if (center) p += center;
    p += s;
    cout << p << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант
Заводим массив на количество символов в алфавите.
Проходимся по строке и считаем каждую букву (+1 в массив для букву)

Допустим AABCCAD

Тогда в массиве будет A=3 B=1 C=2 D=1

Дальше проходим по массиву и составляем строку по правилу

While (array[A] >= 2) то добавляем букву в начало и в конец строки, делаем array[A]-2;

При этом смотрим if (array[A]%2 != 0) Если число не кратное, то запоминаем его в переменную. 
После прохождения всех элементов массива в середину строки записываем символ который мы запомнили.

Таким образом мы получим строку
ACACA