# Является ли строка палиндромом. Если да, вернуть 1, если нет, то - 0

Tags: c, строки

Я уже написала код, но проблема в том, что мне выдают ошибки. Выражение должно быть доступным для изменения левосторонним значением. Кто бы мог предложить решение?

```
int is_palindrome(const char str[]) {
         int x = 0;
         while (str[x] != '/0') {
             if (str[x] >= 'a' && str[x] <= 'z') {
                 break;
                 return 0;
             }
             if (str[x] >= 'A' && str[x] <= 'Z') {
                 int key = 3;
                 str[x] += key;
                 if (str[x] > 'Z') {
                     key = str[x] - 'Z';
                     str[x] = 'A' + key - 1;
                 }

             }
             return 1;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Не знаю что такое Палиндром. В вопросе суть не указана. В 99.9% случаев это никогда не пригодится. Определение чёткое написать в вопрос, для чайников.

Comment: Ставить после `break` оператор `return` - это сразу же логическая ошибка. Компилятор warning должен выдать. Или одно должно быть, или другое. Представьте валидный код.

Comment: Что-то вы не то делаете. Что такое, по-вашему, палиндром? Ваш код вообще делает стран(ш)ные вещи... Ну, а ошибка - вы зачем-то начинаете изменять переданную **константную** строку. Зачем?

Comment: Да вот, практически ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766421/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%8b правда не понимаю чем он автору вопроса не понравился. Вполне хороший рабочий вариант. @Harry плюсик:) А вопрос практически дубль.

Comment: @nick_n_a, там решение для С++ с использованием STL, а здесь С.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такое решение, например:

```
int is_palindrome(const char str[]) {
  int len = strlen(str);
  if (len == 0) return 1;  // Пустую строку будем считать палиндромом

  const char* pbeg = str;             // Указатель на первый символ
  const char* pend = str + len - 1;   // Указатель на последний символ

  while (pbeg < pend) {               // Цикл пока указатели не встретятся
    if (*pbeg++ != *pend--) return 0; // Сравнить символы и передвинуть указатели
  }
  return 1;  // Несовпадений не найдено, это палиндром
}
```

Здесь два указателя идут навстречу друг другу, и если встретятся неодинаковые символы, значит строка при чтении с начала не совпадает с ней же при чтении с конца. Соответственно, это не палиндром. Проверять нужно пока указатели не встретятся.
А если указатели встретились, значит это палиндром.

P.S. Для проверки на палиндром без учета регистра символов нужно немного изменить операцию сравнения:

```
if (tolower(*pbeg++) != tolower(*pend--)) return 0;
```

Правда, не факт, что это будет работать для национальных алфавитов. Там уже надо конвертировать все в UTF-16.

P.P.S. Для фраз естественного языка проверку на палиндром нужно производить без учета пробелов, поэтому программа заметно усложнится. Проще всего создать временную копию строки без пробелов и делать проверку на ней.

```
int is_palindrome(const char str[]) {
  int len = strlen(str);
  char* str2 = (char*)_alloca(len);  // Зарезервировать буфер для копии строки

  const char* p = str;
  char* p2 = str2;
  while (*p) {   // Копируем строку во временнуй буфер пока не встретится завершающий 0
    if (*p != ' ') *p2++ = *p;  // Пробелы пропускаем, остальные символы копируем
    p++;
  }

  if (p2 == str2) return 1;  // Пустую строку (или только из пробелов) будем считать палиндромом

  const char* pbeg = str2;   // Указатель на первый символ
  const char* pend = p2 - 1; // Указатель на последний символ

  while (pbeg < pend) {      // Цикл пока указатели не встретятся
    if (tolower(*pbeg++) != tolower(*pend--)) return 0;  // Сравнить символы без учета регистра и передвинуть указатели
  }
  return 1;  // Несовпадений не найдено, это палиндром
}
```

Comment: Детская классика: "А роза упала на лапу Азора" - не пройдет :) А непонятная вам фраза - из диагностики компилятора, что const в качестве lvalue не работает...

Comment: @Harry, добавил вариант для case-independent. А, это сообщение об ошибке. Я почему-то подумал, что это из условия задачи и весь мозг сломал.

Comment: Вообще-то я имел в виду пробелы... :)

Comment: @Harry, тут надо бы у ТС уточнить условие. Мне кажется, под "строкой" имеется в виду именно строка С, а не фраза естественного языка. Но адаптировать алгоритм несложно, хотя константность аргумента немного мешает.

Comment: Мне кажется... что задачу на палиндром не нужно "размазывать" на два вопроса.